# W3c Validator HTML 4.01 Transitional - whats wrong here?

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

Here is my piece of code which gives me error:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div><span>Text</span></div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <div>Link</div>
              </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

An error:

**document type does not allow element "DIV" here; missing one of "APPLET", "OBJECT", "MAP", "IFRAME", "BUTTON" start-tag**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div>` elements are not allowed inside `<a>` elements (until HTML 5 which doesn't use DTDs and supports the transparent content model).

(The DTD allows applet, object, map, iframe and button inside a elements, and it allows div inside all those elements, but the specification forbids the combination of those two factors in the text, it is a limitation of DTDs which is why the valdator suggests that as a fix).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a `div` (block element) inside an `a` (inline element).

```
<a href="#">
    <div>Link</div>
</a>
```